# Using opted-out customer list as a control group for targeted promotions

Tags: control-group

I have a targeted email promotion list and I want to create a control group.  My friend wants me to use the "do not contact/opted out" list as a control group, but I would think that those kind of people are different from the general population. Is this a best practice?  If not, is there any case where it is proper?

Comment: What's the point of the control group?  Is it basically that you hope to draw causal inferences by comparing it to your targeted list?

Comment: Yes, I want to measure lift between the control and target groups.

Comment: You can't do that.  Randomly assign the target customers into 2 groups & run an a/b test.